# Zend Db Table update adding "?" instead of update value

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have used Zend_Db_Table update on many occasions but this time I am running into a problem. I am not sure why so please tell me where I am doing wrong.

```
$where = $directory->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id = ?', $id);

$total_votes = array('total_votes' => '(total_votes + 1)');

$directory->update($total_votes, $where);

/// $directory is a db table variable.
```

It's not updating value in the database. I printed query using Profiler:

```
**UPDATE dealers_directory SET `total_votes` = ? WHERE (`id` = 3)**
```

I am not getting why it's adding "?" instead of (total_votes + 1). I have used it in couple of places in same application and it's working fine but I don't know whats problem here.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you carefully compared how you're using this method between this section and other sections that are working correctly? I've found that this sort of careful comparisons help me notice subtle mistakes I've made between sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`new Zend_Db_Expr('(total_votes + 1)')`](http://caphrim.net/tim/?p=769).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's working now. Can you please tell me why it was so as I had tried simple value i.e. 2 but it was still showing "?" instead of 2.

Comment: Unfortunately, no - my experience with Zend is quite limited, and I can't think of a good reason. That sounds like something you would best notice yourself.